# Mysql - Select all rows with special characters (but ignore space)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a query to identify what rows have special characters in them, but I want it to ignore spaces

So far I've got

```
SELECT word FROM `games_hangman_words` WHERE word REGEXP '[^[:alnum:]]'
```

Currently this matches those that use all special characters, what I want is to ignore if the special character is space

So if I have these rows

```
Alice
4 Kings
Another Story
Ene-tan
Go-Busters Logo
Lea's Request
```

I want it to match
`Ene-tan`, `Go-Busters Logo` and `Lea's Request`

Comment: Maybe you should first define what you believe to be the special characters you are interested in

Comment: Anything that's not alphanumeric, or a space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply extend your class.

```
... WHERE word REGEXP '[^[:alnum:] ]' ...
```

for only a "regular" space (ASCII 32) or

```
... WHERE word REGEXP '[^[:alnum:][:space:]]' ...
```

for all kind of white space characters.